# Nginx not taking care of a url without backslash

Tags: nginx, web-deployment

I am having a strange problem with my nginx configuration. If I am hitting url with out backslash(/) at the end of the url then my web application is not getting loaded whereas if I put a backslash(/) everything works fine. for e.g if I am hitting `https://qc.example.com/testhtml`, the url is automatically rewritten to `https://qc.example.com:8080/testhtml/` and nothing renders on the page. But if I add a backslash `https://qc.example.com/testhtml/`, the web page successfully renders.

Below is my conf file.

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    error_log  /app/log/nginx_error.log;
    root /app/testhtml;
    index index.html;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /app/ssl/qc.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /app/ssl/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /testhtml {
         root /app;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

It will add trailing slash to the URL

```
    server {
        listen       8080;

        rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

        error_log  /app/log/nginx_error.log;
        root /app/testhtml;
        index index.html;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /app/ssl/qc.example.com.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /app/ssl/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /testhtml {
             root /app;
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```